# How can a barbarian rage more often without taking levels or feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, barbarian

[Barbarian](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm) is frequently cited as an excellent 1-level- or 2-level-long class. When the wizard can use the 2nd-level spell [*rope trick*](http://www.d20srd.org/search.htm?q=rope%20trick) [trans] (*PH* 273) to make the adventuring day 15 min. long, a lone [rage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm#rage) per day is acceptable,<sup>1</sup> but until then—or if on a clock or if the party is without a wizard for some reason<sup>2</sup>—one rage a day just isn't enough.

**What ways are available to a creature that can normally rage but once a day to rage more often *without* taking class levels or feats?**<sup>3</sup>

The cheap is preferred over the expensive, the obvious over that necessitating DM intervention, the official over the third-party, and the published over the custom-made, but I suspect options are so few (mostly magic items and spells) that this list can be inclusive without being excessive, so any sources are acceptable. Finally, *Pathfinder* changed how the barbarian's [rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Rage-Ex-) functions, so options from that game are probably unacceptable.

If it matters, my character is currently a barbarian 1/fighter 1/ranger 1/totemist 1 who ends up with an even wilder array of classes by level 20, but will only ever have a Use Magic Device skill bonus of +3 and no other spell list but the ranger's. Other party members are a bard, a binder, a beguiler, a shadowcaster, and a warlock (hence the need for more rage). The other party members are experts with the skill Use Magic Device, and, if I need rely on them to do so, they can use on my behalf just about any magic item.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Or, more appropriately, the rage variant [whirling frenzy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/classFeatureVariants.htm#rageVariantWhirlingFrenzy), as that's what my character has.
<sup>**2**</sup> Such as in a campaign like the one I'm in wherein players agree to play classes of Tiers 3 to 6. (No, nobody's multiclassing into commoner.)
<sup>**3**</sup> For example, the feat Extra Rage (*CW* 98), the prestige class totem rager (*MoI* 153-7), and the prestige class runescarred berserker (*Una* 31-2) don't do me any good; I've classes and feats picked already. I already know that a custom magic item that grants the feat Extra Rage has an estimated cost of between 10,000 gp and 20,000 gp (*AE* 128), so don't include that.

Comment: I think barbarian is touted as a dip more for the *other* things you can get, plus hey, 1/day you do get rage, than because people assume 15-min. workday so 1 rage is all you need. Though Extra Rage is a fairly solid feat (way better than taking barbarian levels for that purpose!).

Comment: @KRyan O, sure, the rage is largely secondary once pounce is on the board (and, sometimes, the feat Improved Trip *sans* prerequisites), but for my character who's the party's melee brute, the whirling frenzy is shockingly important... and sadly limited. (The party worries the rest of the day after I've whirling frenzied; I feel like I'm holding them back like a wizard!)

Comment: You could play Ravenloft and get a low WILL save, so any horror you face has a decent chance to make your rage kick in, no matter if you used it already :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There're at least two ways...

The following let the barbarian *actually* rage using his own kind of rage more often than normal. ["Whirling frenzy is otherwise identical to the standard barbarian rage"](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/classFeatureVariants.htm#rageVariantWhirlingFrenzy) (*UA* 66), so these should work with that, too.

- The 2nd-level Drd spell ***blood frenzy*** [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 33) causes 1 touched creature to rage as if it used its special ability rage normally "but this rage does not count toward the creature’s number of rage attempts per day." *Note:* Rage attempts?

  This is likely the best choice, equipping an ally with a *wand of blood frenzy* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (90 gp/charge) and the barbarian himself with a *potion of blood frenzy* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (300 gp; 0 lbs.) in a potion bracer (*Sharn: City of Towers* 158, 159) (100 gp; 1.5 lbs.) for emergencies (that is, if the DM's not ready for the [ready-drink helm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59272/8610) to enter her campaign.)
- The shoulders slot item ***mantle of rage*** (["New Magic Items"](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/MagicItems.pdf) 2) (6,000 gp; 1 lb.) grants the wearer, if a barbarian, the ability to rage 1 additional time per day, and, if not a barbarian, the ability 1/day to rage like a level 1 barbarian.

### ...And a clutch of edge cases

In addition to the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*rage*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/rage.htm) [ench] (*PH* 268) *et al.* (which isn't *really* rage but a buff spell with attached penalties), there are a few lesser alternative sources of barbarian rage not involving taking levels or feats.

- The **gutworm** (*Fiend Folio* 220) is a symbiont that at will can cause the host to "enter a frenzied state identical to a barbarian’s rage" for 4 rounds, but this rage explictly provides bonuses like the typical level 1 barbarian's rage. *Note:* More rage, but not the right *kind* of rage.
- The face slot item ***mask of fury*** (*Dragon* #324 76) (12,000 gp; 2 lbs.) 2/day grants the wearer the ability to take *either* a free action (if he's been wounded within the last hour) *or* a standard action and deal himself 3 hp of damage (if he hasn't been wounded within the last hour) to enter a rage "as the barbarian ability." *Note:* Whether this can be a barbarian wearer's *own* rage or *must* be the rage of a level 1 barbarian is the DM's call.
- The supernatural ability **past life** (*DMG2* 159-60) has one option that 1/day can grant the possessor the ability to enter explicitly a greater rage as a level 11 barbarian. This special ability is nominally for NPCs and has a (ridiculous) Level Adjustment of +5. *Note:* Probably too late for this barbarian *and* too stupid for any PC (or, for that matter, any PC's follower or cohort).

Yes, that last scrapes the barrel's bottom.

Answer (score 3):

**There aren't many options left.**

Class levels and feats aside; other than scrolls with the [Rage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/rage.htm) spell, magic items that would duplicate rage would be pretty expensive.

- A domain draught (Magic Item Compendium) of the [Passion Domain](http://webpages.charter.net/tedsarah/Pathfinder/srd/spellLists/Domains/passion.htm)
  would give you a *rage* once per day for a number of rounds equal to
  cleric level. You don't have a cleric level, so it would be 0 rounds.
  Since that is a supernatural ability, not a spell-like ability, you
  would be able to apply the Extend Rage feat to it. That would be a
  "free" [Rage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm#rage) 1/day for 5 rounds.
- [Extend Rage](http://therafim.wikidot.com/extend-rage) could be had for the price of 3,000 gp by suffering
  through an Otyugh Hole (Complete Scoundrel) for a week. Extend Rage
  also applies to Frenzy and making it last an additional 5 rounds.

That may or may not suit your fancy. But there may not be many other options besides feats and class levels.