# How can the spell blood frenzy be put in an eternal wand?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

My barbarian needs [**more rage**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64220/8610), so I'd like to equip the party with an *eternal wand of blood frenzy*, but an *eternal wand* can only employ an arcane spell.

How can an *eternal wand* (*Magic Item Compendium* 159-60) holding the 2nd-level druid spell *blood frenzy* [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 33) be created?

---

#### Notes

There's no druid in the party, but several characters have the skill Use Magic Device far in excess of mine and *at least* one has the feat Craft Wondrous Item, so using the *eternal wand* once created is not a big deal for them, and supplying obscure prerequisites, if necessary, can be done with relative ease. Being level 5 with appropriate wealth by level, I'm relying on 300-gp *potions of blood frenzy*, and, while that's reasonable (I don't really think I'll *need*, over the course of the 15 remaining levels, 15+ *potions of blood frenzy*), it's reassuring to have a times-per-day item rather than a bunch of expendable ones. Further, I know that a *wand of blood frenzy* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) (90 gp/charge; 0 lbs.) costs, initially, only a small amount of gp more than a corresponding *eternal wand* and I could use that instead, but the campaign's a long-term one and, if I end up not needing the *wand*, the potential resale value of such a used *wand* will likely be less than the resale value of the *eternal wand*. (As an aside, an *eternal wand* doesn't make me involuntarily mentally calculate how much each round of combat costs me monetarily—hey, peace of mind is important, even for a barbarian.)

My initial thoughts were the feat Southern Magician (*Races of Faerûn* 168) or befriending a monster that casts druid spells as arcane spells, but the former's no help because "[t]he actual source of the spell's power doesn't change" (so it's still a divine spell albeit a confusing one), and the *Monster Manual* lacks appropriate creatures capable of the latter.

Pricing Information:

> Spell Level: 2<sup>nd</sup>; Caster Level: 3<sup>rd</sup>; Price (Item level): 4,420 gp (9th); Spellcraft DC: 16; Costs to Create: 2,210 gp, 176 XP, 3 days

Other Prerequisites:

[Craft Wand](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64220/8610), [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWondrousItem), the [spell](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/blood-frenzy) contained in the eternal wand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re looking for an arcane hierophant, basically.

Alternative Source Spell from *Dragon* vol. 325, pg. 61, lets an arcane spell count as divine or vice-versa, at a cost a −1 penalty to caster level. It requires that you already be able to cast both arcane and divine spells before you can take it. It’s a pretty common trick for early entry into prestige classes (e.g. a Druid 3/Wizard 1 could take it at 3rd, assuming the wizard level was already taken at that point, and could prepare his 2nd-level druid spells as arcane and thus qualify for mystic theurge), but would also work for this purpose.

Alternative Source Spell does not have the caveat about power source that Southern Magician does.

The arcane hierophant does not need to have any other of the requirements for the eternal wand; those can be supplied by others.

Note also that the −1 penalty to caster level does not *prevent* the arcane hierophant from using spells. You could thus arguably make the eternal wand at caster level 2nd, instead of 3rd, saving you some money.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option would be to have a wizard research an Arcane version of the desired spell, and then creating the eternal wand.
It is a core way of doing it, though requires explicit DM approval, takes in-game time and resources, has a chance to fail and requires a well-stocked library to conduct research in.

This question: [Rules for creating new spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/rules-for-creating-new-spells) has more info in this topic

Answer (score -3):

If you have access to Heroes of Horror and the Eberron Campaign Setting, an ally can make it an arcane spell with only 3 levels of archivist, a level of wizard, and a few levels of artificer. First off, find a scroll of *blood frenzy*, then scribe it into your prayerbook. Then, scribe it as an arcane spell, put it into your spellbook, and then make the eternal wand.

EDIT: Basically, just go Archivist 3 (so you can scribe 2nd level spells into your prayerbook), then go Wizard 3 (you'll need 2nd-level spells for both wizard and archivist). Then go Artificer 6 (just to get Craft Wand and a large enough craft reserve), and craft that Eternal Wand as a wizard, using your craft reserve to fund it. Sure, higher level than would be expected, but it sets you up for greater cheese.

Comment: Could you walk through those steps in a little more detail? Also, is it possible for several of these dudes to conspire to get this done instead of a lone creature being an unlikely (unholy?) combination Archivist X / Artificer X / Wizard 1?

Comment: I don’t see what artificer is allowing you to do here (per the *Eberron Campaign Setting* errata, artificer scrolls are explicitly neither arcane nor divine and therefore cannot be put in any prayerbook or spellbook), but nevertheless I see nothing here that converts the divine spell into an arcane one. Scribing a scroll requires preparing the spell, and creates a scroll of *that spell* precisely as you had it – you can’t prepare it as an archivist and then scribe it as arcane, because the archivist spell is not arcane.

Comment: Ah, found the line I was looking for: “The spell must be of the correct type (arcane or divine). Arcane spellcasters (wizards, sorcerers, and bards) can only use scrolls containing arcane spells, and divine spellcasters (clerics, druids, paladins, and rangers) can only use scrolls containing divine spells. (**The type of scroll a character creates is also determined by his or her class.**)” When you prepare *blood frenzy* as an archivist, i.e. a divine spellcasting class, and use it to produce a scroll, you get a divine scroll. You cannot then put that in the wizard spellbook.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Thank you for your reply. Usually, when answers rely on complicated subsystems like this it's useful to detail the steps necessary to realize them. (We're all experts here, but our areas of knowledge differ.) Thank you for helping strangers.